# android app is not visible on playstore - android tv

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an app on playstore which works fine on android phones. Now I have added support for Android TV as well and my app is approved by google as well. (I checked in play console ). But still I cannot view my app for installation in my TV playstore.
[image: approval on play console]

Here is my android manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  package="com.escean.taj777">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false"/>


    <application
        android:banner="@drawable/banner"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name="com.escean.taj777.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.escean.taj777.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.escean.taj777.UserLanding"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Leanback launcher intent-filter is wrong. Replace the ".action.ACTION_MAIN" with ".action.MAIN"

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: App not showing in playstore on MiTV Stick and displays that "App is Not Compatible with this device". The app's Android manifest has "<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/><category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>" AND "<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true" />".

Comment: Make sure you have the banner defined in your manifest: `<application android:banner="@drawable/banner" >` and also the touchscreen not required permission: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />`

Comment: The issue is solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66595856/android-tv-app-cant-be-installed-on-android-tv-devices/69777175#69777175